# oneclass SVM skewed data in outlier detection with scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am detecting outliers in a dataset using a oneclass SVM with scikit-learn. I'll try to explain my problem with an example:

Imagine a simple dataset with the features height and performance (this is just a simplification, my data set is much bigger). What I want to detect is outliers when there is a weird combination between the two features, for example:

```
h - height
p - performance

h p class
----------
10       0.1         1

12       0.5         1

20       3.2         1

24       2.9         1

23       0.4        -1

...
```

I'm scaling the data set, and I'm training and detecting outliers using a configuration like that:

```
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(kernel="rbf", nu=0.01, gamma=0.01)
```

When my data set is proportionate there is no problem. However, when the  data set is skewed in the following way I have a problem:

- All the heights perform around 3 or 4, but the heights around 10 perform around 0. 
  Then the oneclass-SVM chooses the heights around 10 as the outliers instead of choosing the values such as height 30 and performance 0.2.

I have solved the problem training 2 SVM splitting the heights in two groups (the heights around 10 in one data set and the others in the second data set).

Is there a way to solve it without splitting the data set?

Comment: You should consider scaling your data and changing gamma. Plot your data in 2d and see if the results make sense.

Comment: @AndreasMueller thanks for the answer. However, the data that I showed is just an example. My real data has many more features, so, I guess that plotting in 2d is not really feasible to see the problem. I already scale the data before the training. When you suggest to change the gamma, in which direction? I have been playing with different values and the result stays the same.

Comment: How did you scale the data? Using MinMaxScaler or StandardScaler would be good, with that the default value of gamma might work. Usually for RBF kernels I'd grid-search gamma and C, but if you don't have any ground truth that is hard. You could label some.

Comment: Btw, if you say you have many more features, I don't understand how your observation applies. You were very concrete about the values. What is your observation in the higher dimensional space?

Comment: @AndreasMueller, I think that you are right by saying that the problem is the choice of gamma. I wish I could plot here some visual tests that I did to explain my conclusions to other people that has the same doubts. Thanks for the tips!